# Macro to show/hide status bar in excel

Tags: vba, excel, statusbar

I've been googling this and couldn't find an answer, so I post it for the record, this a macro to show or hide the status bar in excel:

Comment: How is it possible that you did not find an answer on Google? If I [google for "excel vba hide status bar"](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+vba+hide+status+bar) there is a ton of tutorials plus the official Microsoft documentation on the first page. If you did not find something on Google you used Google wrong.

Comment: There's no macro ready to copy-paste to change the state of status bar (shown or hidden) - so you can then assign a keyboard shortcut. Show me a link and I'll erase this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub status_bar()

' shortcut: ctrl+shift+k

    If Application.DisplayStatusBar = "True" Then
        Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Else
        Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You can simply say  If Application.DisplayStatusBar Then   I believe

Comment: You can even toggle the state of status bar in one line: `Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not Application.DisplayStatusBar`